# How to create new columns from data in column A in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet where all the data is in column A. I want to make separate columns from every 9 cells

Move cells to columns

[image]

Is VBA the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge. If you already have tried something please share it with us, then we might be able to help.

Comment: VBA is not the best way to do this.

Comment: Welcome @Bill! Isn't [**this solution**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/transpose-sequences-of-rows-into-columns-ending-with-one-row-per-sequence/73829/7?u=johnsun) right for you? Yes, it can be done with a macro as well, but @FlexYourData is absolutely right - ***VBA is not the best way to do this***

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you try formulas.

Such as `=IF(OFFSET($A$1,MOD(COLUMN(A1)-1,9)+(ROW(A1)-1)*9,)=0,"",OFFSET($A$1,MOD(COLUMN(A1)-1,9)+(ROW(A1)-1)*9,))`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `=INDEX()` function to reorganise your data.

For example, if your  input is in worksheet column `A` starting at cell `A1`and you want the top-left cell  of your output to be in cell `C10` then use the following formula in cell `C10`

`=INDEX($A:$A,9*(ROW()-ROW($C$10))+1+COLUMN()-COLUMN($C$10))`

If you want the dimensions of the output to be something other than 9 columns wide, substitute your chosen value for the 9 in the formula. Similarly, if the input  doesn't start on row 1

This formula can then be copied to the remainder of your output area.

If you have Excel for Microsoft 365 or Excel 2021 then you can incorporate the type of substitution suggested by @Emily but without the cumbersome repetition by using the `=LET()` function. For example:

`=LET(cell,INDEX($A:$A,9*(ROW()-ROW($C$10))+1+COLUMN()-COLUMN($C$10)),IF(cell=0,"",cell))`

or

`=LET(cell,INDEX($A:$A,9*(ROW()-ROW($C$10))+1+COLUMN()-COLUMN($C$10)),IF(ISBLANK(cell),"",cell))`

Comment: So why the down-votes. Both solutions work.